# Postgresql wrong casting from float8 to decimal(24,8)

Tags: postgresql, casting, rounding, postgres-12

using Postgres 12.4 I found some inconsistencies rounding between float8 to decimal(24,8)

By doing

```
select 
  29314.630053404966::float8::decimal(24,8) as num1,
  29314.630053404966::decimal(24,8) as num2
```

the return is:

```
num1: 29314.63005341 -> wrong
num2: 29314.63005340 -> correct
```

As you can see the rounding does not work properly

Any way to cast correctly from float8 to decimal(24,8)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is wrong. `float8` is a binary type, not decimal. Rounding almost always introduces a rounding error, and rounding twice can add two rounding errors.

Answer (score 4):

I would always use `decimal` instead of using `float8` if I wanted to store decimal point values.

why? there is an example

```
SELECT 0.1::decimal(24,8) + 0.2::decimal(24,8); --0.30000000

SELECT 0.1::float8 + 0.2::float8; --0.30000000000000004
```

we can see the `0.1::float8 + 0.2::float8` will get the wrong number.

more detail can refer by [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

> Any way to cast correctly from float8 to decimal(24,8)?

There is a way that might help you do that

we can try to cast the value as a string first, Before Casting `float8` to `decimal(24,8)`.

```
select 
  29314.630053404966::float8::varchar(40)::decimal(24,8) as num1,
  29314.630053404966::decimal(24,8) as num2
```

This way might work, but that will cause performance issues.

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad9e3ec0c53f59b9db4f99c2c8d26c6c)